# How to pass 1-n values for a single multiselect dropdown in gherkin test automation

Tags: datatable, multi-select, gherkin

Assume a dropdown displaying a multiselect option (Pick all the animals you want to save from a shelter: dog, cat mouse, bird, moose etc...) The list gets quite long.

I want to write a feature file with a data table for testdata.
Obviously I would need 1:n combinations on animals to select. *(Maybe there is business logic on combinations, like "cats eat birds", so I have to run all kinds of specific combos, not just randoms)*

I know how to handle the selection technically in the execution code but somehow I'm stuck with how to define and pass the test data from the feature file to the step definition in a clean sensible way.

Approach one, would be multiple data columns like

```
| animal-1 | animal-2 | animal-3 | animal-4 | animal-5 | ... |animal-n|
| dog      |          |          |          |          | ... |        |
| dog      | cat      |          |          |          | ... |        |   
| dog      | cat      |          | fish     |          | ... |        |
...
| dog      | cat      | bird     | fish     | mouse    | ... | moose  |
```

and then using different parameters like

`And select "animal-1", "animal-2", "animal-3", "animal-5", ... , "animal-n" to save from shelter`

This would obviously be stupid, for passing 80% empty values and the number of columns potentially needing to be as big as the number of existing values in the drop down (for a select all)

Approach two, is to concatenate them and then have a tokenizer and loop in the execution code, so like

```
| animalselection                   | 
| dog                               |
| dog,cat                           |
...
| dog,cat,bird,fish,mouse,...,moose |
```

with the feature file sentence being

`And make "animalselection" to save from shelter`

This seems better, but only works for data where you can clearly define a delimiter.
I have sometimes not just nicely named animals but very dirty unstructured data derived from manual input over decades. Think of department an org names from companies that can be like

- Human Resources, Contracting
- Human Resources - Social Security
- Manuf. Plant A Dept. 17
- Campaign team "We make $$$ in 2019"
- EU DSGVO §5 team

How do I pass multiple unstructured values from a data table for the different executions to the step definition?

I tried both and it somewhat worked but it is clumsy and ugly as f***.
Google and the Smartbear documentation didn't help at all.

Stackoverflow, you are my only hope.

**UPDATE**
I found a solution but it only works for our exact setup of testing software. We use Cypress as the runner and this supports JSON test data files, so called fixtures. You can reference a file in the data table of the scenario file.

```
| selection   | 
| animallist_1 |
| animallist_2 |
...
| animallist_n |
```

with the feature file sentence being
`And make "selection" to save from shelter`

Cypress then uses the values inside the `animallist_x` JSON files.

This is nice an my solution for now but maybe someone still comes up with a native solution without using another tool.